# Acceptance rate nagging getting out of hand?

Tags: discussion

This comment:

> Alice, are you thinking about choosing
>   an answer? You've collected quite a
>   bunch of answers and it would be good
>   if you mark that or those you think
>   that answers your question. That's how
>   SO works. Otherwise, it's unclear if
>   your question has been answered or
>   not.

was posted 20 minutes or so after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169322/when-to-use-pointers-in-c) was originally asked on SO. I really think the acceptance rate nagging is getting out of hand - perhaps we could have a clear statement in the blog or somewhere that people don't have to immediately accept answers, and should in fact wait to give people a chance to reply? As it happens, the replies to this question were rather poor, so I would be sympathetic with the OP not accepting any of them.

Answer (score 7):

I've never really been a fan of the whole "accept rate" thing, at all. Stack Overflow exists for people to ask questions and give answers. It simply doesn't matter if the person who asked the question understands the mechanics of the site enough to "accept" it - if they spend enough time here and care enough, they'll figure it out.

Answer the **question**, not the **asker**. Zillions more unnamed people will eventually see the same question and answer through Google search. Some of them might even vote your answer up.

Comment: I completely agree. I admit that in my earlier days I may have made some gentle remarks about accepting answers. But I have grown to understand the mission of SOFU - answer the questions.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah... That's *waaay* too soon to *expect* someone to accept an answer, much less feel justified in nagging them about it.

Flagged.

Answer (score 3):

While I think that answers that solve the problem should be accepted - if nothing else it stops the Community user bumping the post if it's been inactive for a while - I also don't think that constant nagging helps. Perhaps I should start flagging particularly snide comments.

I'm sure that there used to be a prompt about accepting an answer when you viewed your question.

This is one of the more polite comments I've seen, but it's still wrong to post it against a new question.

If you feel that strongly just don't answer the question.

**UPDATE**

I just checked the question and the OP has only asked four questions and has accepted answers on the other three, so the OP clearly knows how SO works. So I flagged the comment too.

Answer (score 0):

I find it o.k. to leave a comment, or to not answer, if an asker with more than 20-30 questions has a rate below 40-50%.

But to nag about accepting an answer in a specific question? That's not o.k., not even after a day. The asker may be wanting to do some more research, plan to put up a bounty after two days, or simply be away from their machine.